# using https with wpf and owin package

Tags: c#, wpf, owin

So I'm using a wpf application and a webserver inside using the owin package. this works like a charm however i want to be able to use https. when googled some i came across owin.https. 
Followed this sample but my webclient only throws exceptions and does not connect. When googling some more abouthow to use this i came across the setting enable ssl set to true altough since i'm using a desktop application i do not have nor see this setting in the projects properties.

What I have done so far:

startup class:

```
appBuilder.UseForcedHttps(4430);
```

webserver:

```
string baseAddress = "http://localhost:" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"];
string secureAddress = "https://localhost:" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PortSecure"];
var options = new StartOptions();
options.Urls.Add(baseAddress);
options.Urls.Add(secureAddress)

// Start OWIN host 
using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(options)) ;
```

Altough this does not seem to work, any idea how to get https working and do i need to work with certificates to?

Comment: In which way doesn't it work? Any error message? Anyway if you try to monitor incoming HTTPS requests, make sure you have certificate mappings configured properly, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background (Yes, even when you use OWIN self hosting, not IIS). Learn those `netsh` commands.

Comment: i have checked with netsta -an to see if it was listening on the port and yes it did, my client throws an aggrgate exception with httpexception, socketexceptio and iostreamexception. I have never worked with certificates in application before tough, but i do have knowledge of hwat it is and handshaking of tls

Comment: `netstat` is useless in this case, as merely monitoring a port doesn't mean HTTPS connections can be made.